# WPF Application hosting WCF Access Violation

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

I've been reading up (apparently not that well) on hosting a small WCF service inside a WPF application. It's a suite of tools that has a master tray application that acts as the information distribution point between them all.

When I try and create the new service host I get an access violation, simplified code as follows:

```
    [ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
       BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
       RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
       ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
       UriTemplate = "/SampleMethod")] 
    [OperationContract]
    void addSearch(object data);
}
```

MyService.cs

```
    public class MyService: IMyService
{
    // Instantiate the API wrapper class.
    private MainWindow.api myApi = new MainWindow.api();

    public void addSearch(object data)
    {
        myApi.addSearch(data);
    }

}
```

Then in the onload event of my main WPF Window error is:
*A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll

The program '[13672] MyApplication.vshost.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.*

```
        Uri httpUrl = new Uri("http://localhost:8090/MyService/Test");
        //Create ServiceHost
        // **ERROR HERE
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService), httpUrl);
        //Add a service endpoint
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyService), new WSHttpBinding(), "");
        //Start the Service
        host.Open();
```

App.manifest

```
<security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
  <applicationRequestMinimum>
    <PermissionSet Unrestricted="true" ID="Custom" SameSite="site" />
    <defaultAssemblyRequest permissionSetReference="Custom" />
  </applicationRequestMinimum>
</security>
```

I've been reading tutorials on this so it's probable I have misunderstood something so any pointers are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The error 'Access Violation' actually occurs for any syntax error in a WPF application hosting a WCF service.

System.ArgumentException is the important one, obviously indicating I had some of the arguments wrong. I'm just testing a working example and will post back with code that works!